# VBA ByRef Argument Type Mismatch When Using Function In If Statement

Tags: vba, variant

I am having a weird issue when I'm calling a function from another function inside an `if` statement. I defined a `Sub`, which I am using to test this function, and it calls on a function which relies on another function I use to compare values. The code is below, which should make things clear. Essentially, I don't understand how it's possible for the code to work fine in the `print` statement, and then throw an error in the `GetMatch` function. I appreciate any help.

Edit: All of a sudden everything works. Do debugging breakpoints affect the program? I haven't changed anything, but CStr() is no longer required when calling GetMatch. I haven't touched any of the subs or functions, but I did clear some breakpoints. If I find what caused it, I'll post a solution. Thanks for the help everyone.

Edit2: Maybe this is a bug with VBA? If I add the CStr() option to the indexOrder(...) calls, things work. Before, without the CStr() options, things did not work. Now, strangely enough, after using the CStr(), I am able to remove the CStr()'s entirely from the program, and things work again. It breaks if I undo to the point where they weren't there originally though. I don't know what this could be, but if anyone has an explanation, I'm very interested. Thanks

```
Sub testFind()
    Dim SortOrder() As Variant
    Dim indexOrder() As Variant
    SortOrder = Array("Contact Email", "Last Name", "First Name", "Attempt #", "Customization", "Template #")
    indexOrder = Array("First Name", "First Name", "Template #", "Customization")
    findAndReplace(indexOrder, SortOrder)
End Sub


Function findAndReplace(indexOrder As Variant, list As Variant) As Variant
    Dim indexLength As Integer
    Dim listLength As Integer
    Debug.Print TypeName(indexOrder(0)) ' Identifies as String
    indexLength = getVariantLength(indexOrder)
    listLength = getVariantLength(list)
    Debug.Print GetMatch(CStr(indexOrder(1)), CStr(indexOrder(1))) ' This works fine. Returns 0 as it should
    If GetMatch(indexOrder(1), indexOrder(1)) = 0 Then ' Fails with ByRef error
        Debug.Print ("Why don't I work?")
    End If
End Function


Function GetMatch(A As String, B As String) As Integer
    A = Trim(A)
    B = Trim(B)
    If (IsEmpty(A) Or Trim(A) = "") Then
        GetMatch = 1
        Exit Function
    ElseIf (IsEmpty(B) Or Trim(B) = "") Then
        GetMatch = -1
        Exit Function
    End If
    GetMatch = StrComp(A, B, vbTextCompare)
End Function

Function getVariantLength(vari As Variant) As Integer
    If IsNull(index) Then
        getVariantLength = 0
    Else
        getVariantLength = UBound(vari) - LBound(vari) + 1
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: If the GetMatch works when changing the value to a str using Cstr() why not use it on the IF statement? `If GetMatch(CStr(indexOrder(1)), CStr(indexOrder(1))) = 0 Then`

Comment: OK, that does work, but why? The TypeName returns a string value on the Variant, why doesn't it pass it as one to the argument?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a Sub vartest() or Function vartest(), it's trying to call a sub/function that doesn't exist, or at least it isn't included.

Edit: You aren't doing anything with the function. A function will return a value, a sub will 'do' something. You need to assign a variable to whatever it returns, or do a MessageBox or some other way of returning the value.

The next issue is it's trying to call a function getVariantLength() that isn't defined or listed.

Comment: Sorry, I had a vartest, it was replaced. I erased the wrong test function in my code.

Comment: No problem. When it's asking for a Variant and you're trying to give it an integer, long, double, etc.. you can just convert that value to a Variant with CVar().

http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/cvar.php

Comment: Thanks, that's good to know actually. It looks converting it to a string, also works, but I don't know why.

Comment: I do use the GetMatch value though. It's used when I call `Debug.Print GetMatch(...)`